# Selecting columns and showing their sum

Tags: sql, select, oracle12c

I am trying to calculate the total sales generated from web site orders in my Oracle 12c Database as well as some information about the orders involved (their id, inventory item IDs, item quantity, and item price) and display the total sales as well. The query I have come up with is:

```
SELECT L.O_ID, L.INV_ID, L.OL_QUANTITY, L.OL_PRICE, SUM(L.OL_QUANTITY * L.OL_PRICE)
FROM ORDERS O, ORDER_LINE L, ORDERSOURCE S
WHERE
S.OS_DESC = 'Web Site'
AND O.OS_ID = S.OS_ID
AND L.O_ID = O.O_ID
GROUP BY L.O_ID, L.INV_ID, L.OL_QUANTITY, L.OL_PRICE;
```

which displays the order ID, inventory id, quantity, and price, but also displays a fifth column which just has the total price for each row (quantity * price) whereas I wanted the sum of each row's total price.

I've looked around and seen a `GROUP BY... WITH ROLLUP` statement recommended, but when I try to execute it that way I get an "SQL command not properly ended" error.

Edit: information about the error was requested. Here is the full text:

```
Error starting at line 1 in command:
SELECT L.O_ID, L.INV_ID, L.OL_QUANTITY, L.OL_PRICE, SUM(L.OL_QUANTITY * L.OL_PRICE)
FROM ORDERS O, ORDER_LINE L, ORDERSOURCE S
WHERE
S.OS_DESC = 'Web Site'
AND O.OS_ID = S.OS_ID
AND L.O_ID = O.O_ID
GROUP BY L.O_ID, L.INV_ID, L.OL_QUANTITY, L.OL_PRICE WITH ROLLUP
Error at Command Line:7 Column:54
Error report:
SQL Error: ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended
00933. 00000 -  "SQL command not properly ended"
*Cause:    
*Action:
```

Comment: I just modified the original question to display the full text of the error message.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT L.O_ID, L.INV_ID, L.OL_QUANTITY, L.OL_PRICE, 
       SUM(L.OL_QUANTITY * L.OL_PRICE)
FROM ORDERS O, ORDER_LINE L, ORDERSOURCE S
WHERE S.OS_DESC = 'Web Site'
  AND O.OS_ID = S.OS_ID
  AND L.O_ID = O.O_ID
GROUP BY GROUPING SETS ((L.O_ID, L.INV_ID, L.OL_QUANTITY, L.OL_PRICE), ());
```

> GROUPING SETS are a further extension of the GROUP BY clause that let
>   you specify multiple groupings of data. Doing so facilitates efficient
>   aggregation by pruning the aggregates you do not need. You specify
>   just the desired groups, and the database does not need to perform the
>   full set of aggregations generated by CUBE or ROLLUP. Oracle Database
>   computes all groupings specified in the GROUPING SETS clause and
>   combines the results of individual groupings with a UNION ALL
>   operation. The UNION ALL means that the result set can include
>   duplicate rows.

As I understand you need the whole total + ordinary GROUP BY. In this case both ROLLUP and CUBE will produce some extra results so it's better to use GROUPING SETS where you can choose what are you going to group.

Comment: Nice! That was exactly what I needed. If I wanted to run the same type of select statement in MSSQL and MySQL, would I need to change  anything?

Comment: @ThomYorkkke Yes, I think so because ROLLUP/CUBE/GROUPING SETS are Oracle specific functions. If you want something universal you can use UNION ALL instead, but I suppose it will be slower (in Oracle)